# Authenticate JWT-bearer token using ASP.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a Web API project which uses [Microsoft OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) for authentication. The resulted bearer token needs to be verified or authenticated in the Web API project in Startup.cs.

Here are what the decrypted token looks like, I don't find any useful information other than the Issuer and Audience.

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "oOvcz5M_7p-HjIKlFXz93u_V0Zo"
}. {
  "nameid": "9f3e1329-2717-61ec-78weu-887ed4ccf1f1",
  "scp": "vso.agentpools_manage vso.build_execute vso.code_manage vso.dashboards_manage vso.extension_manage vso.identity vso.project_manage vso.release_manage vso.serviceendpoint_manage vso.taskgroups_manage vso.test_write vso.variablegroups_manage vso.wiki_write vso.work_full",
  "aui": "b021930d-1a1b-4104-890d-ebcdfccdf1ac",
  "appid": "bd8435c5-70d6-418a-e8923-f5595c06290c",
  "iss": "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
  "aud": "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
  "nbf": 1627395683,
  "exp": 1627399283
}.[Signature]
```

I have been trying to authenticate the request using the following code in Startup.cs but always getting 401.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
             .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.SaveToken = true;
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                 {
                     ValidateIssuer = true,
                     ValidIssuer = "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
                     ValidateAudience = true,
                     ValidAudience = "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                     IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey
                 };
             });
```

Once we authenticate the token, the same token will be used for Azure DevOps API authentication.

I have some doubts,

- Is it possible to authenticate the token generated using [Microsoft OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops)
- If yes, please let me know where I'm missing.
- Is there any other way we can handle this

Added few more details

```
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.SaveToken = true;
                 options.Authority = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize";
                 options.Audience = "C00979C5-41E9-40BA-BE30-7B12D4F1D669";
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                 {
                     ValidateIssuer = true,
                     ValidIssuer = "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
                     ValidateAudience = true,
                     ValidAudience = "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                     IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey
                 };
             });
```

Getting following error

```
Content root path: D:\Projects\DevOpsSmartBoardV2\DevOpsSmartBoard\DevOpsSmartBoard
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
       ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. HttpResponseMessage: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', HttpResponseMessage.Content: 'System.String'.
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
```